# Vim does not like brackets

Tags: vim

I have a problem that have been bothering me for days now.

Whatever I do, I simply cannot place any single `{`,`}`,`[` or `]`.

Every time I try, it takes me up to the next or previous paragraph. I've looked it up and I can't find a good way to unmap it and finally have my azerty keyboard to behave correctly so I can peacefully code

Comment: in which mode are you on? It seems that you are in normal mode, while you may want to be in insert mode.

Comment: Sidenote: there is a [vi and vim stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) (in beta).

Comment: I am in insert mode (pressing I or the "insert" key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, Problem Solved ! I had to uninstall and reinstall the Ubuntu bash on windows 10 multiple times and it worked ! Thanks for the help everone !

Comment: You might have to file this as a bug in vim's issue tracker or ubuntu's issue tracker. That might help future users to solve this issue. Any related bug might be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In the normal mode, press `'i'` to enter the insert mode.
And you can start to edit your file.

After everything is done, press the `'ESC'` key and then `':wq'` to save your modification.

Comment: `:wq` always updates the file, even when no changes were made. `:x` is not only shorter, but only saves *if* changes were made. `ZZ` does the same as `:x`, and is easier to reach (at least on QWERTY layouts).

Comment: I know all that, but thanks anyway, and insert mode does not inserts brackets either.

Answer (score 1):

Vim / vi has several different **modes**. This dates back to the times when you would edit using a teletyper, i.e. no "**vi**sual" representation of the data you are editing, no mouse etc.

With only the "usual" keys at your disposal, you need to *navigate* in the data, you need to *insert* data, and you need to execute *commands* on the data. Not so coincidentially, these are the three modes of Vim / vi, and in each mode, the keys do something differently.

---

By default, the editor starts in the "normal mode", which you will use to navigate, and enter the other modes from.

*In this mode*, `)` moves you to the end of the sentence, `(` to the previous sentence. `}` and `{` do the same for paragraphs, combinations of `[` and `]` work with chapters.

If you enter "insert mode" (most simply by pressing `i` in "normal mode"), you can enter all the above letters normally. You exit "insert mode" by pressing `<Esc>`. You will recognize "insert mode" by `-- INSERT --` being displayed in the bottommost line of the screen.

If you *are* in "insert mode", and pressing any of the above keys *does* move your cursor instead of entering the corresponding symbol, there is some (broken) configuration at work. Check your `~/.vimrc`, and if necessary, rename it and try again with a "clean" configuration.

---

It is next to impossible to do Vim / vi justice in the scope of a SO answer. It is very much an *expert*-friendly editor, not a *novice*-friendly one. You need to actually *learn* how to use this editor, but it is absolutely worth it in the long run.

Comment: That is a hell of an answer ! Thanks man but i had looked up  and knew mostof it, the only thing I don't understand is the `~/.vimrc` part.

Comment: @JulesLasne: Did that solve your problem, then? More (broken) configuration might be in `~/.vim`, or even -- if your system administrator was a real {beeeep} -- in `/etc/vim/*`.

Comment: No it did not. The thing is, either in normal or insert mode, it stills makes me move around paragraphs with {}[].

Comment: So that is why i was asking more about the ~\vimrc part

Comment: At startup, Vim looks in a number of locations for a "vimrc" file, and if it finds it, executes the commands in it. This is meant to allow for user-specific configuration. It is possible to completely screw up such a configuration to the point where the brackets are mapped to movement even in insert mode, as you described -- it certainly is not default behaviour. So, it's not Vim that's broken, it's your configuration. Try `:help vimrc` (in Vim) to read up on the details. Another possibility is some braindead plugin, which would be in the `.vim` directory.

Comment: Just found out that starting Vim with `vim -u NONE` allows you to start without reading any such config / plugin code. Check if your brackets behave then.

Comment: Alright i'll try all that and i'll keep you up to the news :D

Comment: Well it did not work. I ran through all the vimrc and vimrc.tiny files i could find but none had anything else that comments

Comment: @JulesLasne: I cannot really help you there. Your Vim installation is most definitely broken, but I cannot tell how / why.

Answer (score 0):

In `insert mode`, you should be able to insert brackets without trouble.

In `normal mode`, those correspond to motions.

To go to `insert mode` from `normal mode`, press `i`.

See: `:h object-motions`

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what i do every single time but it never worked. I press AltGr and then the 4 key to get a `{`but yeah, in insert mode, I press the `{`button and it moves the things back up one paragraph and gets back in normal mode.